Powershell script is holding a file during append resulting in error
I am trying to write script to extract some data from json and then append them to .txt file for my next Use-Case.
When I execute code below:
$columns = "ID_Report","Name","Created_by","Last_mod_by"

$file = Get-Content -Path "W:\Personal\Ulrich\VA-Scraping\reports.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$key_first = "items"

Write-Output "$($columns[0]);$($columns[1]);$($columns[2]);$($columns[3]);$($columns[4])" > xxx.txt

foreach ($record in $file){
    if ($record | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $key_first -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ 
        foreach ($item in $record.items){
            "$($item.id);$($item.name);$($item.createdBy);$($item.modifiedBy)" | Add-Content "W:\Personal\Ulrich\Skriptiky\xxx.txt" 
        }
    }

}

I get many errors resulting in truncation of exported data:
Add-Content : The process cannot access the file 'W:\Personal\Ulrich\Skriptiky\xxx.txt' bec
ause it is being used by another process.
At line:12 char:82
+ ... tem.modifiedBy)" | Add-Content "W:\Personal\Ulrich\Skriptiky\xxx.txt"
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (W:\Personal\Ulrich\Skriptiky\xxx.txt:String) [A 
   dd-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddCon 
   tentCommand

Is there a way to fix this?
Edit:
Tried direct aproach, but still the same result.
Changed the code to code below and looks like it works better now.
$columns = "ID_Report","Name","Created_by","Last_mod_by"

$file = Get-Content -Path "W:\Personal\Ulrich\Skriptiky\VA-Scraping\reports.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$outfile = "W:\Personal\Ulrich\Skriptiky\VA-Scraping\vystupy\$(Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd).txt"

$key_first = "items"

Write-Output "$($columns[0]);$($columns[1]);$($columns[2]);$($columns[3]);$($columns[4])" | Out-File -FilePath $outfile

$file | ForEach-Object {$_.items } | ForEach-Object {Write-Output "$($_.id);$($_.name);$($_.createdBy);$($_.modifiedBy)"} |  Add-Content "$outfile"


I take this as answered, thank you for your advices.

Have you tried not using the redirect approach, and just write directly to the file in the first statement?

@LasseV.Karlsen Yes, i tried it now and still the same output.

Can you edit in your new attempt in your question?

I don't know why this happens (I suspect that W: is a special network? drive) but as an aside from the fact that wrapping cmdlets in a loop is a performance killer, correcting this, will probably resolve your issue: $File | ForEach-Object { use the current object ($_) for $record } | Add-Content ... (or even directly ... | Set-Content ... ).

Thank you, that helped and it seems like its working better now. Yes W: is network drive.
